# displaying an image using Html helper

Tags: cakephp, html-helper

I'm trying to display an image in a view

```
<?php echo $this->Html->image('upload\6.png',array('alt' => 'uploaded image'));?>
```

but i'm getting a this icon instead :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/noJ4L.png

upload folder is inside webroot\img\

what's wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention you developing environment.. Its a good idea to use forward slash(`/`) what ever the OS is.

This should work-

```
<?php echo $this->Html->image('upload/6.png',array('alt' => 'uploaded image'));?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code, you need to include the "img" in your image link and replace "\" with this "/". :)

```
<?php echo $this->Html->image('img/upload/6.png',array('alt' => 'uploaded image'));?>
```

Comment: That won't work, it will resolve to `/img/img/upload/6.png`. There is no need to prepend `img` to the path, all that is needed is changing the backslash (``\``) to a forward slash (`/`).

Comment: maybe that file did not exist in app/webroot/img/upload?? Haha! try this link "img/upload/6.png" , "/img/upload/6.png"